# How to fix "InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes" when calling model.fit() in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, multidimensional-array, tensorflow-datasets

As a total TensorFlow beginner, I am attempting to get a semantic image segmentation model working using TensorFlow Keras' functional API and a per-pixel categorical cross-entropy (at least that's the intention):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os

tf.enable_eager_execution()

NUM_TRAINING_SAMPLES = 123
NUM_CLASSES = 24
RES_WIDTH = 256
RES_HEIGHT = 256
BATCH_SIZE = 5
NUM_EPOCHS = 3

images = np.random.random((NUM_TRAINING_SAMPLES, RES_WIDTH, RES_HEIGHT, 3))
annotations = np.zeros(((NUM_TRAINING_SAMPLES, RES_WIDTH, RES_HEIGHT, NUM_CLASSES)))
one_hot_pixel = np.eye(1, NUM_CLASSES)[0]
annotations[:, :, :] = one_hot_pixel
map(np.random.shuffle, annotations[:])

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images, annotations))
dataset = dataset.batch(3)

def conv_block(input_layer, num_filters):
    layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters, (3, 3), padding='same')(input_layer)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(layer)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(layer)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters, (3, 3), padding='same')(layer)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(layer)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(layer)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(layer)
    return layer

def deconv_block(input_layer, num_filters):
    layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(num_filters, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(input_layer)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(layer)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(layer)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters, (3, 3), padding='same')(layer)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(layer)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(layer)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters, (3, 3), padding='same')(layer)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(layer)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(layer)
    return layer

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(RES_WIDTH, RES_HEIGHT, 3)) # 256
encoder0 = conv_block(inputs, 32) # 128
encoder1 = conv_block(encoder0, 64) # 64
encoder2 = conv_block(encoder1, 128) # 32
encoder3 = conv_block(encoder2, 256) # 16
encoder4 = conv_block(encoder3, 512) # 8
center = conv_block(encoder4, 1024) # center
decoder4 = conv_block(center, 512) # 16
decoder3 = conv_block(decoder4, 256) # 32
decoder2 = conv_block(decoder3, 128) # 64
decoder1 = conv_block(decoder2, 64) # 128
decoder0 = conv_block(decoder1, 32) # 256
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(NUM_CLASSES, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(decoder0)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs]) #model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[images], outputs=[output])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=40, callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs')])
```

For now, I am simply simulating input data, and I am aware that my annotations are the same for every pixel. I just want to have something training initially. However, when I run this, I get the following stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-0905074e93d1> in <module>
     63 model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
     64 
---> 65 model.fit(dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=40, callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs')])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    849           validation_steps=validation_steps,
    850           workers=0,
--> 851           initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
    852     elif distributed_training_utils.is_tpu_strategy(
    853         self._distribution_strategy):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py in model_iteration(model, data, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch, mode, batch_size, **kwargs)
    189       progbar.on_batch_begin(step, batch_logs)
    190 
--> 191       batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
    192       if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    193         batch_outs = [batch_outs]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
   1177     if self.run_eagerly:
   1178       outputs = training_eager.train_on_batch(
-> 1179           self, x, y, sample_weights=sample_weights)
   1180     else:
   1181       if not isinstance(K.symbolic_learning_phase(), int):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_eager.py in train_on_batch(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights)
    258 
    259   outs, loss, loss_metrics, _, masks = _process_single_batch(
--> 260       model, inputs, targets, sample_weights=sample_weights, training=True)
    261   if not isinstance(outs, list):
    262     outs = [outs]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_eager.py in _process_single_batch(model, inputs, targets, output_loss_metrics, sample_weights, training)
    212             output_loss_metrics=output_loss_metrics,
    213             sample_weights=sample_weights,
--> 214             training=training)
    215       if loss is None:
    216         raise ValueError('The model cannot be run '

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_eager.py in _model_loss(model, inputs, targets, output_loss_metrics, sample_weights, training)
    140           weighted_masked_fn = training_utils.weighted_masked_objective(loss_fn)
    141           output_loss = weighted_masked_fn(
--> 142               targets[i], outs[i], weights, mask=mask)
    143 
    144       # If the number of outputs is 1 then we don't append the loss metric

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py in weighted(y_true, y_pred, weights, mask)
    645     """
    646     # score_array has ndim >= 2
--> 647     score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
    648     if mask is not None:
    649       mask = math_ops.cast(mask, y_pred.dtype)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py in categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits)
    484            'keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy')
    485 def categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=False):
--> 486   return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    487 
    488 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in categorical_crossentropy(target, output, from_logits, axis)
   3866     epsilon_ = _to_tensor(epsilon(), output.dtype.base_dtype)
   3867     output = clip_ops.clip_by_value(output, epsilon_, 1. - epsilon_)
-> 3868     return -math_ops.reduce_sum(target * math_ops.log(output), axis)
   3869   else:
   3870     return nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=target, logits=output)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    810     with ops.name_scope(None, op_name, [x, y]) as name:
    811       if isinstance(x, ops.Tensor) and isinstance(y, ops.Tensor):
--> 812         return func(x, y, name=name)
    813       elif not isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
    814         try:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py in _mul_dispatch(x, y, name)
   1076   is_tensor_y = isinstance(y, ops.Tensor)
   1077   if is_tensor_y:
-> 1078     return gen_math_ops.mul(x, y, name=name)
   1079   else:
   1080     assert isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor)  # Case: Dense * Sparse.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py in mul(x, y, name)
   5854       else:
   5855         message = e.message
-> 5856       _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   5857   # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
   5858   _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [3,256,256,24] vs. [3,0,0,24] [Op:Mul] name: loss/conv2d_252_loss/mul/
```

I am aware it has something to do with my simulated dataset, but I'm not sure what to do next. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Some of your models layers have dimension with 0. You can view that using model.summary().

Comment: That's a great tip! Totally forgot about model.summary(), thanks!